# Handbrake start button greyed out

Tags: handbrake

I'm running Handbrake rev 5474 (x86_64) under Kubuntu 14.04.  The Start button is greyed out. As far as I know, I have the latest version.  There are a number of reports of this problem from 2010, but the solutions proposed there are all version-related. How can I get the transcription started?

Comment: I think the current version of handbrake is 0.10.5

Comment: Many such issues with Handbrake are solved by adding the Handbrake developer's PPA: https://launchpad.net/~stebbins/+archive/ubuntu/handbrake-releases?field.series_filter=trusty Give that a try and see if the issue is resolved....

Comment: Charles, how did you identify the current version of Handbrake?  Usually Help provides that information, but in this case it just gives what I cited, namely, rev 5474.  I don't know how to get the real version number such as 0.10.5.